# How do i run a shell script, in a shell script with the menu dialog?

Tags: bash

here is my un finnished script i guess, what im aiming to do is make it so it lists my scripts, and i want to be able to run the selected .sh file that is listed. thanks for the help in advance. i tried maybe making( optionone= 1 ) because maybe the tag "1" will be recognized as the name of the .sh file listed? so in my result area i tried result=$(./${optionone})

i dont want to type and file names to run it, im trying to make it easy, like a control pannel where i can just click enter on a file name and it runs for me..

```
`#!/bin/bash
let i=0 # define counting variable
W=() # define working array
while read -r line; do # process file by file
    let i=$i+1
    W+=($i "$line")
done < <( ls -1 /home/peder/Desktop/scripts )
FILE=$(dialog --title "List of scripts" --menu "Chose one" 24 80 17 "${W[@]}" 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3) # show dialog and store output
clear
optionone= 1
 case $FILE in
    0 )
      clear
      echo "Program terminated."
      ;;
    1 )
      result=$(./${optionone})
      display_result "Scripts"
      ;;
    2 )
      result=$(C^)

      ;;
  esac

  done
```

`
PICTURE ONE:

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMIDy.png)

PICTURE TWO:

[what it looks like executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcS1W.png)

Comment: You can find working examples of menus made with both `dialog` and `zenity` in the bash shellscript code of **dus** (mkusb-dus) at this link, http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/dus. (There is a general description of mkusb at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Comment: i will be checking this post in 24hrs, just incanse you think this is not active, i am just on a fixed schedule, early replies are greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Introduction

The following set of files work for me, when all of them are in an own directory. You may want to make your menu system more general.

### menu

```
#!/bin/bash

# this simplified version works with files in its own directory

i=0 # define counting variable
wa=() # define working array

while read -r line; do # process file by file
    let i=$i+1
    wa+=($i "$line")
done < scripts

result=$(dialog --title "List of scripts" --menu "Choose a script from the list" 24 80 17 "${wa[@]}" \
 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3)      # show dialog menu

#clear

if [ "$result" == "" ]
then
 echo "Quit"
else
 item=$(($result*2-1))
 #  test output (to be removed later on)
 echo "$item"
 echo "${wa[$item]}"
 read -p "Press Enter to continue or ctrl C to quit"
 # end of test output
 "${wa[$item]}"       # execute selected item
fi
```

### scripts

```
./test0
./test1
```

### test0

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $0 start
echo $0 end
```

### test1

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $0 start
echo $0 end
```

Comment: Thanks @sudous i re made your example into my own and learnt a ton from it, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, @PederSkaaravik. I'm glad that my answer could help you :-)